# Hadoop singleton pattern uasge

Tags: java, hadoop, design-patterns, singleton

I'm trying to implement singleton which is going to cache and validate configuration of map reduce jobs in hadoop. Let's name it `ConfigurationManager`.

Here is what I have for now:

```
public class ConfigurationManager {
    private static volatile ConfigurationManager instance;
    private static final String CONF_NAME = "isSomethingEnabled";
    private boolean isSomethingEnabled;

    private ConfigurationManager(Configuration configuration) {
        this.isSomethingEnabled= configuration.getBoolean(CONF_NAME, false);
    }

    public static void init(Configuration configuration) {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (ConfigurationManager.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    this.instance = new ConfigurationManager(configuration);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static ConfigurationManager get() {
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isSomethingEnabled() {
        return isSomethingEnabled;
    }
}
```

As you can see it is designed to be thread-safe. Moreover it is not standard singleton: I separated initialization and accessor methods not to enforce presence of hadoop's `Configuration` instance on `get` call. So to use it I prematurely call `init` in the ancestor of `Tool` and then trying to access my singleton using `get` in reducers (like this `ConfigurationManager.get().isSomethingEnabled()`), but for some reasons `get` returns `null`. Could somebody, please, explain such a behaviour? Maybe maps/reducers are initiated as separate processes?

Comment: I don't see any zero-argument `get()` method. And why is hadoop relevant to your question?

Comment: @shmosel, sorry for inaccuracy. Fixed. Hadoop is relevant to my question because obvoiusly this code is working in isolated environment (tested this). I is not working as soon as I put it in conditions I described.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, you're saying you called `get(Configuration)` before calling `get()` and are surprised to see null. How did you ensure the initializer would run first?

Comment: Each reduce task runs on a different jvm. which explains the null.

Comment: @Venkat, that really explains all the issues. Could you, please, post this as a separate post, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each reduce task runs on a different jvm. Which would explain the null.

You can do it per reduce task in : [Reducer - configure](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConfigurable.html#configure-org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf-)